# rails + paperclip + plupload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, plupload

Hi i'm using paperclip and plupload like in this tutorial:
http://www.theroamingcoder.com/node/50

It works.
But if i try to set thumbnails with paperclip like:

```
has_attached_file :data, 
    :styles => { :medium => "558x418>", :thumb => "60x82>" }
```

It doesn't work. 
I receive this error:

```
[paperclip] identify -format %wx%h '/tmp/stream20110209-26212-1l2obtp-0.png[0]' 2>/dev/null
[paperclip] convert '/tmp/stream20110209-26212-1l2obtp-0.png[0]' -resize "558x418>" '/tmp/stream20110209-26212-1l2obtp-020110209-26212-cl5lbg-0' 2>/dev/null
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::PaperclipError: There was an error processing the thumbnail for stream20110209-26212-1l2obtp-0>
[paperclip] identify -format %wx%h '/tmp/stream20110209-26212-1l2obtp-0.png[0]' 2>/dev/null
[paperclip] convert '/tmp/stream20110209-26212-1l2obtp-0.png[0]' -resize "60x82>" '/tmp/stream20110209-26212-1l2obtp-020110209-26212-1m6qvkj-0' 2>/dev/null
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::PaperclipError: There was an error processing the thumbnail for stream20110209-26212-1l2obtp-0
```

How can i solve it?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to disable chunks in plupload

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you don't have Imagemagick installed!

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php

If I am wrong try this

```
has_attached_file :data, :styles => { :medium => ["558x418>", :png], :thumb => ["60x82>", :png] }
```